# ImageMagick to ffmpeg using python and subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, imagemagick, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to make a blend between some images using

```
blend = Popen(['convert', 'test_images/*.jpg', '-delay', '10', '-morph', '10', '-'], stdout=PIPE)
```

and pipe the output to ffmpeg to write a video from the image sequence

```
video = Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-r', '30', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', 'test.mp4'], stdin=PIPE)

for _ in range(15):
    video.stdin.write(blend.stdout.read())
video.stdin.close()
```

I'm trying to do it all in memory and not write to disk. All I get currently is a 50kb mpeg4 file which does not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made 4 images going from red, through orange, yellow to blue as follows:

```
convert -size 256x256 xc:red    1.png
convert -size 256x256 xc:orange 2.png
convert -size 256x256 xc:yellow 3.png
convert -size 256x256 xc:blue   4.png
```

and, just for a quick check, morphed them together into an animated GIF with 34 frames:

```
convert [1234].png -morph 10 result.gif
```

[image]

Then I checked what `ffmpeg` can read on its `stdin` and it seems to be able to read multiple `PPM` (Portable Pixmap) files concatenated together, so I told **ImageMagick** to make PPM files as follows and fed that into `ffmpeg`:

```
convert [1234].png -morph 10 ppm:- | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 30 -i - output.mpg
```

Note that the order of options is important: `-f image2pipe` needs to be used as an input option (before `-i`).

I got out a working MPG video that I can't post, but it works.

I guess now that you can get files into `ffmpeg` you can diddle around and get the type of output you seek - hopefully! A little experimentation, and some friendly advice from @LordNeckbeard seems to indicate that this should work:

```
convert [1234].png -morph 10 ppm:-  | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you for filling in the blanks in my knowledge! Teamwork rules :-)